# Passing Callback to an Activity in a library

Tags: android, android-activity, callback

A library that I am using has an Android activity. I would like to pass a callback to the activity to get notified of certain user events like when user enters a specific code or draws something on the screen. I am not able to find a way to pass callbacks to the android activity.

**Note:** I can edit the library, however, I prefer to leave the activity within the library for architectural reasons and ease of testing without integrating with the larger app.

What is the best possible way to solve this? Are there any Android design patterns?

Comment: "to get notified of certain events" -- please explain what these events are.

Comment: CommonsWare Thanks. Edited: I would like to pass a callback to the activity to get notified of certain user events like when user enters a specific code or draws something on the screen. I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best possible way to solve this?

Modify the activity to post an event on an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, `LocalBroadcastManager` when these things occur. Then, listen for those events elsewhere in your app.

> I prefer to leave the activity within the library for architectural reasons and ease of testing without integrating with the larger app

Then convince the developer of the library to modify the activity to post an event on an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, `LocalBroadcastManager` when these things occur. Then, listen for those events elsewhere in your app.

Or, convince the developer to offer some other means of accomplishing this (e.g., you subclass the activity and override certain methods to be notified of these events).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have access to the library src code, so create an AIDL interface for communication between your app and the lib. You can set up a callback via AIDL and have the lib send your app the data in real-time as it gets generated.
There's quite a bit of code involved but it is achievable. You can start here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl